# Open VSCode from MSYS2 with 'code' command

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

I am not able to open a Visual Studio Code window from a MSYS2 terminal using the `code` command (`command not found` error). I have thoroughly followed the steps mentioned in the [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and both MSYS2 and VSCode `bin` folders are on my `Path` variable.

Although this is not a deal breaker, as one can open the folder in VSCode and then navigate to the directory in MSYS2 in the integrated terminal, it does cause some minor inconvenience.

Comment: who what you see in your `PATH` in the MSYS2 shell's environment, and show where your VS Code executable is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem was that VSCode's bin directory was not added to MSYS2's `PATH` (thanks to [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/user)'s comment). There was no mention of doing this as a method of troubleshooting in the official guide, so I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/6212) there.

The following line of command fixed the problem for me:

```bash
PATH=/c/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/'Microsoft VS Code'/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Alternatively, open MSYS2 shell using `msys2_shell.cmd -full-path` to inherit the system-wide PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems to only work temporary, until you close the window. I found a permanent solution though:

1. Open *Bashrc* with *nano ~/.bashrc
2. Go to *Execute*
3. type: *export PATH="/c/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft* VS Code/bin: *$PATH"*
4. Close bashrc and type: source ~/.bashrc

Comment: @Steve I am not sure if this is the right answer or not, but is definitely not an NAA. It needed edits (still need some more probably).